# Funcion no definida src

Tags: javascript

He hecho un tema anterior y creo que quedo en el olvido o nadie supo responderme y necesito una solucion , bueno lo que sucede es que tengo mi **index.html** y mi **.js principal** y tengo una funcion en el js y esa funcion la llamo en el index.html , lo que sucede es que **cuando la funcion esta escrita en forma de script en el index si funciona pero cuando esta en mi js principal no funciona**

Importando el JS desde el index

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mt6.js"></script>
```

FUNCION:

```
function comprobarCondicion(opcion) {
      this.value = opcion;

      if (opcion == '164.132.203.28:455') {
console.log('Condicion');
      }
}
```

Index

```
onchange='comprobarCondicion(this.value)'
```

ERROR EN CONSOLA:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: comprobarCondicion is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange ((index):277)**

WEB: *http://ogar.pw*

Comment: Parece que **comprobarCondicion** está dentro de una función anónima. Intenta asignar la función a una variable y llamarla desde ahí.

Comment: La mayoría de las veces ocurre esto cuando no encuentra el archivo, por favor, verifica que el nombre del script sea correcto. Si así es, entonces presiona `ctrl + u` y clickea en el script, se debería abrir una nueva pestaña con el código, quizás no salga nada porque la ruta no es la correcta

Comment: @EduardoCampos hazle caso a Genarito, casi siempre ese es el problema

Comment: Era "IIFE" un Guz me ayudo , gracias de todas formas